# How to add FadeIn/Out to my code when I click the separator button?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add FadeIn/Out to this code when I click the separator button?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // Variables
        var objMain = $('#main');

        // Show sidebar
            function showSidebar(){
            objMain.addClass('use-sidebar');
                    $.cookie('sidebar-pref2', 'use-sidebar', { expires: 30 });
                }

        // Hide sidebar
            function hideSidebar(){
            objMain.removeClass('use-sidebar');
                    $.cookie('sidebar-pref2', null, { expires: 30 });
                    }

         // Sidebar separator
        var objSeparator = $('#separator');
       objSeparator.click(function(e) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                    if (objMain.hasClass('use-sidebar')) {
                    hideSidebar();  
                    }
                    else {
                        showSidebar();
                    }
        }).css('height', objSeparator.parent().outerHeight() + 'px');

        // Load preference
        if ( $.cookie('sidebar-pref2') == null ){
            objMain.removeClass('use-sidebar');

        }
    });
```

Does someone have a suggestion?

Comment: Can you make a jsbin or jsfiddle demonstrating your problem? It makes it easier to troubleshoot...

Comment: I have never made a jsfiddle,where do I begin? Thanks.

Comment: It's easy! Just go to http://jsfiddle.net - paste in your html, js, and css. You'll also need to select jQuery if you're using it from the left hand sidebar. Once it's working(or at least showing the error you're experiencing) paste the link to the saved fiddle into your question. If you run into problems let me know!

Comment: Added jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/clight77/5xvxxg50/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery effects such as,

```
$("#yourdiv").fadeIn("slow");
```

to show the div or:

```
$("#yourdiv").fadeOut("slow");
```

to hide it.

More on jQuery effects [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and many other variations with no success :)

// Show sidebar
        function showSidebar(){
        objMain.addClass('use-sidebar');
                $.cookie('sidebar-pref2', 'use-sidebar', { expires: 30 });
                $("#sidebar").fadeIn("slow");
            }

```
// Hide sidebar
    function hideSidebar(){
    objMain.removeClass('use-sidebar');
            $.cookie('sidebar-pref2', null, { expires: 30 });
            $("#sidebar").fadeOut("slow");
            }
```